# Can't add google map to phonegap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, phonegap

I'm trying to add google map js to my phonegap project.

My code (it displayed a white page ):

```
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  app.initialize();
</script>
<script>
  function initMap() {
var myLatLng = {lat: 10.795317, lng: 106.693692};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 17,
  center: myLatLng
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDrTRMjEfm0KlIhDZXih-J9F0arDJ-t_O8&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

i read same issues but i did not handle my error.
Thank you

Comment: Which error you got?

Comment: when i run this code, it show white page

Comment: What sets the size of the map div?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.